# Material UI - closing modal leaves focus state on button that opened it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, focus

Let's say I have a button that opens a `Dialog` component. The button has custom theming/styling to specify various states, one of them being the `:focus` state:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: "#3A7DA9"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button 
        id="button-that-opens-modal"
        className={classes.root} 
        onClick={() => setOpen(true)} 
      >
        Open the modal
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open}>
        <h3>This is the modal</h3>
        <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I've noticed is that every time I have this pattern, (where a button opens a dialog modal), when the modal is closed, the `#button-that-opens-modal` is left with a `:focus` state, which looks bad in terms of styling.  Here's a quick gif:

[image]

### [Codesandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-hill-0hv7z?file=/src/App.js:235-763)

Is this a known issue?  I don't see why the `:focus` should be automatically applied to the button when the modal closes.  How can I stop this?

#### I tried this:

I can add a ref to the button, and make sure to manually unfocus the button in various places.  Adding it in the `onExited` method of the Dialog works, but flashes the focus state for a second:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const buttonRef = useRef();
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        ref={buttonRef}
        className={classes.root}
        onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
      >
        Open the modal
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionProps={{
          onExited: () => {
            buttonRef.current?.blur(); // helps but creates a flash
          }
        }}
      >
        <h3>This is the modal</h3>
        <Button onClick={() => {setOpen(false)}}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### [sandbox showing this very imperfect solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-thunder-tbv3p?file=/src/App.js:243-1204)

And even if I found exactly the right event handler to blur the button such the styling looks correct, this is not something I want to do for every `Dialog` in an app that has many `Button` - `Dialog` pairs.  Is there a Material-UI prop I can use to disable this 'auto-focus' back on the button, rather than having to create a ref and manually `.blur` it for every `Dialog`?

Comment: This is for accessibilty purpose. You can disable it by adding prop `disableRestoreFocus` on your Dialog

Comment: Thank you!  If you want, post this as an answer and I will mark it as such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for accessibilty purpose. You can disable it by adding prop `disableRestoreFocus` on your Dialog :)